# Fetch rows which are updates in last one hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the schema of the database I have a field which of type `timestamp`. (For instance, 2021-05-25 16:48:34.686402, field populated with now())

The rows have to be fetched on the basis of this field, fetching only those records have the value in last 1 hour.

I am trying this query

```
select * from table_name 
WHERE last_updated_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

but it is giving the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
> Position: 98`

Need help on how this usecase can be solved.

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem, where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: Your query has 85 characters, and you are getting the error on the position 98. Are you sure you are not hidding something?

Comment: It is the table name which is different, but position 98 points to the number 1

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is postgresql. updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax in Postgres is:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where last_updated_time > now() - interval '1 hour';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer which worked here

`select * from table_name WHERE last_updated_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour' );`